# How to stop my Character's left arm and gun from rendering twice when he starts running fast?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So initially I had trouble with my character's left arm and gun clipping through objects(not entirely though) and I followed the instructions in this unity3D post to fix this issue(Read through the top answer so you know what I did).

[Solution for FPS gun clipping through walls](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/41298/fps-gun-clippes-through-walls.html)

Now I'm having trouble figuring out how to stop my player left arm and gun from rendering twice when he starts running fast(Doesn't occur when I'm just walking or slightly running). I know it has something to do with there being two cameras but I need an additional camera to stop the gun and the player's arm from clipping through objects.

Here is a picture that shows what I mean.

[image: Arms and weapon being rendered twice]

IF you look closely, you can see that the AK-47's magazine is being rendered twice(there is very small gap there) as well as the left arm. I've fiddled with both camera settings and could not figure out a way to stop this from happening. How do I go about fixing this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable the gun layer from rendering with the first camera. The gun layer should only render on the second camera.